# How do I return a single record using max function and aggregation on table with different values

Tags: ms-access

I have a single table that looks like this:

[image]

I need to return the row with the most recent *LastVisit Date* as highlighted above from a single table.

I tried using the MAX function on the date but the problem is, I cannot aggregate the  other columns because the values are not the same, this returns all three rows.

How do I get only the latest row highlighted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DMax` to get the most recent `LastVist` date.

```sql
DMax("LastVisit", "YourTable")
```

Then to get the row (or rows) with the same date, use that `DMax` expression in a query `WHERE` criterion.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE LastVisit = DMax("LastVisit", "YourTable");
```

Another way to do it would be to use a subquery instead of `DMax` to get the latest date.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE LastVisit = (SELECT Max(LastVisit) FROM YourTable);
```

Comment: Thanks my friend: So what happens if I need to convert to date? For example, lets assumed the date was in a format like: 20131127.

By the way, this works as needed, thank you so much.

Comment: So are you saying the data type of your `LastVisit` field is actually text instead of Date/Time?

Comment: No in this scenario it is date as shown above, I was just playing around with the code to see other ways I can use it, in different situations.

Comment: OK.  If you have dates as text in yyyymmdd format, `Max()` will return the value which would sort last ... so 20131127 would be considered greater than 20131126 ... and the queries in the answer should still return the row(s) you want.  But if the values were stored in yyyymd format, the task is more challenging.